# An approach for decomposing a book into characters and their interactions?

Tags: algorithm, text, graph, nlp, named-entity-recognition

So I have a book, say it goes linearly with respect to time.

For each paragraph for each frase, we can perform [freeling](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/freeling/demo/demo.php) to get Entities (NP, NN)  actions (VB), and characteristics (Nouns). And we could just throw it all into Neo4J connecting each entity with the next verb and that verb with the next entity. And each new paragraph for same names use the latest detailed entities (from near paragraphs).

Yet if it is so simple why there is no library for that? And what to do with time and complex relations: "Peter told Tomas that his father was a drunk ass." which would turn into `Peter->told->tomas` `father->was->ass` here `that` and `his` should be utilized but how to approach it?

So is there an algorithm that can transform a book into a graph with entities interactions?

Comment: I can't tell from that sentence whether Peter is talking about his own father or Tomas'.  How would an algorithm decide?

Answer (score 0):

FreeLing does what you ask for.  Check for "semantic graph" output level.

This will use depencency parsing to decide which verb is related to which entity (just using the nearest one will not work).  It also uses semantic role labelling to decide who is doing what to who (e.g. the subject is not the same in a passive or active sentence, but the agent *is* the same in both).  Finally, it uses corefernce resolution to decide who is more likely to be the referent of pronouns or posessives (such as "his").

You can select "semantic graph" in freeling demo and see what you get. There you can also see the XML output it produces.